# Forma mas segura para almacenar credenciales de acceso a BBDD

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, php5, seguridad

Hago mantenimiento de una aplicación, en la que las credenciales para conectar a una BBDD mysql (tanto la cadena de conexión, el username y la password, los carga "a pelo" en variables, dentro de un fichero php al que llamaremos a_pelo.php. Este fichero tendría un contenido como esto:

```
<?php 
  $db    = "MiHost:MiPuerto"
  $user  = "fulanito"
  $paswd = "tururu"
```

Luego, cada vez que quiere conectarse mediante @mysql_connect en cualquier punto de la aplicación, hay que hacer un require(a_pelo.php), para poder usar las variables:

```
require(a_pelo.php);
$connection = @mysql_connect($db, $user, $paswd  or die("error de conexion");
```

Esto me parece bastante aberrante e inseguro, y voy a modificarlo para [almacenar las credenciales en un fichero .env](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/variables-entorno-php-env.html) que se guarde fuera del document_root (creo que algunos frameworks hacen esto). Luego, leería de este fichero los datos de conexión (user, passwd, etc.).

La duda viene aquí. No sé si sería lo más aconsejable

A) mantener el a_pelo.php aunque modificado para que, en vez de estar hardcodeados "a pelo" el usuario, contraseña, etc... los lea del fichero de entorno y cargue las variables con ello. Si hago esto, desaparece la información sensible del php, pero sigue siendo necesario hacer un require cada vez que me quiera conectar.

B) prescindir por completo del a_pelo.php, y meter los datos necesarios para la conexión en variables de SESSION que se cargarían desde el fichero de entorno. Esto me parece más correcto, pero tendría que cambiar TODAS las conexiones para usar las variables de sesión en vez de las actuales... y son muchas las conexiones a BBDD que se realizan:

```
// Tendré que cambiar cada @mysql_connect de la aplicación.
$connection = @mysql_connect($_SESSION["db"], $_SESSION["user"], $_SESSION["passwd"] or die("error de conexion");
```

¿Que opción parece mejor, A o B?

Comment: ¿Por qué te agobia tanto esa práctica tan habitual? Esas credenciales están igual de seguras en todas las propuestas que haces... ¿qué diferencias de seguridad percibes entre una y otra opción? ¿Por el ámbito de las variables? ¿Que el fichero esté fuera del root?

Comment: @DavidJP ¿Si el fichero estuviera fuera de root, no le daría un poco más de seguridad en caso de un error de configuración del webserver que permitiera descargar los archivos .php como texto plano?

Comment: @DavidJP Pues es algo que me viene impuesto, por decisiones organizativas del cliente. Quieren evitar contraseñas y demás en los ficheros fuente. He investigado un poco, y aunque es una practica habitual, sí que parece que es recomendable no hacerlo por múltiples motivos (por ejemplo, no tienes porque tener en tu repositorio GIT o SVN... ficheros que contengan las credenciales de acceso a BBDD).

Comment: @Juan Te lo compro. Mejor que esté en un directorio `private` no accesible por el público en general. Pero fíjate que ya nos estamos yendo a un escenario con un servidor mal configurado y, por lo demás, ¿dónde estarían las diferencias?

Comment: @Amok Con respecto al git, se hace precisamente así para excluir el fichero de credenciales del repositorio, con añadir `a_pelo.php` en el `.gitignore` las contraseñas no figurarían en ningún repositorio, únicamente en el hosting

Comment: De hecho tienes un problema de seguridad mayor y es el hecho de que usas *mysql_** para conectarte el cual es una API obsoleta desde hace ya varios años en PHP. Lo cual me lleva a pensar que estás trabajando del mismo modo las consultas y te pone en riesgo de ataques de inyección SQL, sugiero busques en el sitio pues ya existen excelentes publicaciones al respecto